# Array JSON deserialize

Tags: c#, json, list, rss

I'm trying to get the data from a website RSS converting it to JSON. I got this JSON string:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http%3A%2F%2Frss.tecmundo.com.br%2Ffeed

I'm using lists to get the values but I got this error "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface" and I don't know how to solve it. It happens in this line.

```
IList<News> content = new IList<News>();
```

Here is my code.

```
public class News
{
    public string author { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public string contentSnippet { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string publishedDate { get; set; }

    public string[] getFeed(string Website)
    {
        string path = @"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=" + Website;
        var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(path);
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse((string)json);

        IList<JToken> jsonData = jsonObject["responseData"]["feed"]["entries"]["0"].Children().ToList();
        IList<News> content = new IList<News>();

        foreach(JToken data in jsonData)
        {
            News finalData1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<News>(jsonData.ToString());
            content.Add(finalData1);
        }

        return new string[] { "I must return something here." };
    }
}
```

Here is the tool I'm using to visualize better the JSON string: http://jsonschema.net/#/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting has nothing to do with JSON. It is because you're trying to create an instance of an interface. You *could* just fix that by giving it the concrete `List<T>` class:

```
IList<News> content = new List<News>();
```

However, the simpler way of converting the `IList<JToken>` to an `IList<News>` is probably to use LINQ again - you can do all of this in one step pretty easily:

```
 IList<News> content = jsonObject["responseData"]["feed"]["entries"]["0"]
    .Children()
    .Select(token => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<News>(token.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

That compiles, but isn't actually want due to the data you've got. `entries` is an array, so you probably want:

```
JArray array = (JArray) jsonObject["responseData"]["feed"]["entries"];
var content = array
    .Select(token => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<News>(token.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Am I reading my JSON array by the right way? I mean using ["responseData"]["feed"]["entries"]["0"] because now it's returning me that I'm trying to read from an invalid position.

Comment: @ThadeuFernandes: I think it's fine as far as `entries`, but `entries` is an array - I suspect you just want to get rid of the `["0"]` and possibly the `Children()` call. Will edit.

Comment: But if I remove the ["0"] how do I read the ["1"]? Because I have 4 different values in different arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with the json, but with trying to create an instance of an interface which is not possible in c#. You need to create an instance of a concrete class that implements the IList interface. List would be one example. There are others, including arrays.